# Why does the text box value not appear when the value changes?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this code, but I can't see textbox1 value when I run the app! What might be the problem here?

```html
 <button type="button" onclick="Method(@arg)">Action</button>
```

mvc code

```html
@Html.TextBoxFor(r =>r.textbox1,"Class", autocomplete: "Off");
```

```js
function Method(arg) {
    $("#textbox1").attr('value', arg);
    var ipvalue =  $("#textbox1").val();
    $("#textbox2").attr('value', ipvalue);
}
```

Comment: Show the HTML code for textboxes. And the caller of neveshtanMablagh

Comment: include your html as well within the code snippet

Comment: Add html+how you call this function that code too

Comment: Also, don't use `attr()` to set the value, use `val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
neveshtanMablagh("hello");
function neveshtanMablagh(arq) {
    $("#textbox1").val(arq);
    var ipvalue =  $("#textbox1").val();
    $("#textbox2").val(ipvalue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textbox1" />
<input type="text" id="textbox2" />
```

Kindly try this snippet.

Comment: What sort of an explanation is *"Try this way"*?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is there is a difference between the *value attribute* and the *value property*.

When a user edits an input for example, the *value attribute* remains unchanged, the edit is only available in the *value property* of the element

Similarly, updating the *value attribute* does not update the property. Always use `val()` to set values...not `attr('value')`

```
$("#textbox1").val(mablaq);
var ipvalue =  $("#textbox1").val();
$("#textbox2").val(ipvalue);
```